# Why do I get Stackoverflow Exception when calling ToList (after orderBy) on IEnumerable?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by, ienumerable

I have a piece of LINQ code that results in Stack Overflow Exception and I can't figure why. I will keep the code as is since I can't tell which part is the cause.

Consider we have a list of booking records:

```
Class BookRecords
    Public START_DATE As String
    Public END_DATE As String
    Public BOOK_NUM As String
End Class
```

And the task is to find out all records which (1)Start time is within 15 minutes from now & (2)Is consecutive to records in (1).

Here's how I do it:

```
Private Function ValidRec(RecordList As List(Of BookRecords)) As List(Of BookRecords)
    Dim timeNow = Date.Now
    'Valid records by itself
    Dim validRecords = RecordList.Where(
        Function(r)
            Dim startDate As DateTime
            'VVVVV stack overflow thrown at this return
            Return DateTime.TryParse(r.START_DATE, startDate) AndAlso
                   ((startDate - timeNow).TotalMinutes < 15)
        End Function)

    Do
        'consecutive records
        Dim conseRecords = RecordList.Except(validRecords).Where(
                            Function(r) validRecords.Any(
                            Function(vr) vr.END_DATE.Equals(r.START_DATE)))

        If Not conseRecords.Any() Then Exit Do
        validRecords = validRecords.Concat(conseRecords.Except(validRecords))
    Loop

    validRecords = validRecords.OrderBy(Function(vr) vr.START_DATE) _
                               .ThenBy(Function(vr) vr.BOOK_NUM)

    'stack overflow after the ToList line 
    Return validRecords.ToList
End Function
```

The code works fine until after the last line validRecords.ToList. And then stack overflow occurs at the Return DateTime.TryParse ... statement. Size of RecordList and validRecords are small (both 2 in testing) and there're no other threads modifying these Lists/Objects.

Why is this using up the stack? I know the LINQ statements are probably badly structured and creating lots of lists(IEnumerables?) unnecessarily but is that the cause? (that would be genuine stack overflow then, cool)

I figured making validRecords a list instead of IEnumerable would avoid the problem but I'd appreciate if someone could point out the real cause.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have a wrong understanding of what these LINQ methods do. Whenever you call `.Where()`, `.Except()` etc, a new enumerator is created. This enumerator only saves its characteristics (e.g. the `Where` enumerator saves its predicate). The query is not executed yet. It is only executed when the data is needed, e.g. when you call `ToList()` on the enumerator. That's why this is the place the exception is thrown.

In your concrete example, the problem is caused by the `OrderBy` function. Seemingly, it creates an infinite enumeration. However, I could not figure out why. Must be some nasty implementation details.

Anyway. Forcing LINQ into this problem is the wrong way. It is way more efficient and easier to implement it the classical way. This lets you explicitly specify how acceleration data structures are used (e.g. `HashSets` or `Dictionaries`) and when and how often the data is sorted. Due to its local scope, all LINQ enumerator have to re-create this structures if they need them.